# How to use fancyBox to show larger view of post thumbnail (in the WP Loop)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

Has anyone been able to use fancyBox to open the post thumbnail in the WordPress loop? Here is my code so far:

```
       <?php
        $query = new WP_query( 'pagename=about');
        //The Loop
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
              $query->the_post();
              echo '<aside class="clear flex-container">';
              echo '<div class="about">';
              echo '<figure class="about-thumb">';
              echo '<a href="#" class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-                                   thumb">';
              the_post_thumbnail('medium');
              echo '</a>';
              echo '</figure>';
              echo '<div class="about-entry-content">';
              the_content();
              echo '</div>';
              echo '</div>';
              echo '</aside>';
            }
        }

        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```

I have not been able to find an answer to this. Any help appreciated. Thanks.